# Entity framework 4 and multiple database

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Something changes or it still not support this?
For example join database1.dbo.Users and database2.dbo.Addresses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what ais asked is if you can join tables from different databases, not different providers, resulting in **one entity mapped to two or more tables or views from different databases**.

If you think about it, when you create a EDM model with Visual Studio it ask you to give an existing database, and when finished creating the model, it generates an EF connection string, that internally address to the given underlying database connection string.

E.g: *metadata=res://*/EFTestModel.csdl|res://*/EFTestModel.ssdl|res://*/EFTestModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;**provider connection string="Data Source=.\;Initial Catalog=EFTest;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True**"*

So each model matches only a database, only a connection string.

EF4 still does not support creating one conceptual model which works with N storage models. At least this is not supported with any built-in provider. Perhaps in the future this could be done through a new provider that combines the support of many storages (from the same providers or different).

I havent done enough research on it, but perhaps **Windows Server AppFabric (Codename Velocity)** could be the bridge to go through this gap.

Note: I have tried even editing manually the xml for the EDM (edmx) to insert a second  element inside the <edmx:StorageModels> tag but it does not match the EDM XML Schema so VS warns about it:
Error 10021: Duplicated Schema element encountered.

Rafa Ortega
MAP2010

Answer (score 4):

I actually did find a way to make an EF model span multiple databases if your database supports Synonyms. Basically you setup Synonyms to Database2 on Database1, create separate edmx models for each, then merge the XML

I posted the exact steps to make an edmx file span multiple databases [here](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/22/tricking-ef-to-span-multiple-databases/) if you're interested, along with a script to do the merge for you whenever something changes.

Comment: Have you not encountered any issues, in the long term? Is it fully compatible?

Comment: @LuisFilipe The project I did this for actually got cancelled, so I never got a chance to fully test everything. From what I did get a chance to test, the only real restrictions was whatever restrictions are in place for the `Synonyms`. For example, if your Synonym points to another server, you're limited to whatever the SQL rules are for accessing linked servers.

Answer (score 1):

See answer to similar question:

[Entity Framework - Inserting entity with multiple models and databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558309/entity-framework-inserting-entity-with-multiple-models-and-databases/5598664#5598664)