# Does EF Code First support querying multiple databases?

Tags: code-first, multiple-databases

We are using Entity Framework Code First for the first time in our org. One of our queries must span two databases. Here's a SQL query:

SELECT t1.col, t2.col
  FROM DB1..table1 t1
  INNER JOIN DB2..table2 t2 ON t1.key = t2.key

From all of my searching, I don't believe that Code First can support this query. The two workarounds I've read about are creating a view in DB1 that reads DB2.table2, and then do all the queries against DB1 only. The other option is to do separate reads against DB1 and DB2, then merge the data in code.

We're concerned about setting up a bunch of views because it just clutters the DB, and we are worried about performance when merging data.

Is it possible to support the above query through Code First?

Thanks all.

-Troy

Answer (score 1):

The answer is 'no' it doesn't support it (for now?) [from](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/a5e1e545-163d-4c97-aaab-a5f9ce6f58f7/) [all](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/22/tricking-ef-to-span-multiple-databases/%20%22all) [I](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558309/entity-framework-inserting-entity-with-multiple-models-and-databases/5598664#5598664) [have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659942/entity-framework-4-and-multiple-database) [read](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1052345-support-for-multiple-databases). One way to solve this other than views is to use synonyms that point to the other database/schema/table, which has its own caveats.

CREATE SYNONYM (Transact-SQL)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx

Then create your models to point to the synonym's (when using database first I had to create the model from "fake" tables or you could use a script to merge EDMX xml) and JOIN, INSERT, UPDATE, etc. should all work (as well as in EF). Hopefully this is helpful. There may be other options available but I am still looking for them myself.