# Centralized database for common lookup tables

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, entity-framework, database-design

We currently have separate databases per application but I am finding more common tables (ex. countries, employee type) for each database that are replicated. I am considering created a separte lookup database to store all these "lookup" tables. The application databases would then reference the same key in the lookup table which would not only save some space but also allow for cross application/database queries.

Is there an flaw to this design? I don't think I've ever seen it online but most samples online are bound to a single database. The only drawback that comes to mind is the inability to add relationships since that is bound to other tables in the same database. The other issue is .net specific in that I think this would make using the Entity Framework more difficult if not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think EF allow to connect with multiple databases, But if your database support Synonyms, than its possible , this [link](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/22/tricking-ef-to-span-multiple-databases/) might help you.

Below is one more [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558309/entity-framework-inserting-entity-with-multiple-models-and-databases/5598664#5598664) which might help you to how EF can work with multiple databases.

Thanks
Suresh

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the workarounds on the EF issue. But looking back I think my basic question might be too vague or subjective.