# Asp.Net MVC Join data from 2 tables from 2 different databases (Data Service) - entity framework

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have 2 databases. In 1 database I have saved the names in Players table. Example:

Players

```
Id       Name
1        John
2        Jack
```

In other database I have table:

Club

```
Id PlayerId
1  1
1  2
```

I use data service to manipulate with those 2 databases.

I am interested how can I connect those 2 data tables to retrieve the names from Players data table like this:

```
Data
ClubId PlayerId PlayerName
1      1        John
1      2        Jack
```

Do I have to retrieve data from both sources and create new list in memory(controller) with this and than use model to show data from both in view?

Comment: Why are they in two databases?

Comment: Application structure. Back end, front-end are different apps.

Comment: Then what guarantee do you have that player id 1 in the club db has anything to do with id 1 in the players db?

Comment: I did not create database, I am only looking for the answer.

Comment: John,

Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659942/entity-framework-4-and-multiple-database - This might help.

Thanks,

Comment: Based on the link provided by Usman, it sounds like its technically possible to connect to two databases in one EDM. Even if you could, though, how would you maintain a proper PK/FK relationship in the model?  Manually?  That sounds problematic.

Comment: Also, why not fight this issue at the database where the real problem exists?  I'm sure it's not the easy fix, but it sounds like the right one.

Answer (score 0):

If the player database is called Players and the club database called Clubs you could do the following:
    SELECT ClubId = C.ID, PlayerId = P.Id, PlayerName = P.Name *
    FROM Players.dbo.Players P
    INNER JOIN Clubs.dbo.Clubs C
    ON P.Id = C.PlayerId

In other words, to reference an object in another database you have to fully qualify the name:
[db name].[schema].[table name]

Comment: Thanks for contribution. I know how to connect with SQL in ms sql management, but I need this in entity framework.